# TypeError: Data location must be "memory" for return parameter public view returns (address[16]){

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, addresses

I know that is question has been answered in one form. However, I could not find an answer for my specific case.

Here is my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Adoption {
 address[16] adopters;

//Adopting a Pet
function adopt(uint petId) public returns (uint){
  require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);
  adopters[petId] = msg.sender;
  return petId;
}

// Retrieving the adopters
function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16]){
 return adopters;


 }
 }
```

Right now this is throwing a

> TypeError: Data location must be "memory" for return parameter in
>   function

but none was given error and the error is originating from

```
function getAdopters() public view returns (***address[16]***){
```

From my understanding, `memory` is just a key word that creates a temporary variable. Do I need to use a `storage` variable for the public address array?

I am going based off of this tutorial: https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop

Comment: Get rid of that `16` and you should be fine.

Comment: It still throws the same error even when I remove that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use `memory` storage For return struct or array types of data is good
>   practice and it improves the performance of code and from solidity
>   version `0.5.0`, it is compulsory to use `memory` storage for this
>   type of data types.

You have to just put `memory` keyword in return parameter of function getAdopters() like this:

```
function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16] memory){

     return adopters;

}
```